# Type detection: using variadic arguments to properly implement a function that calculates the mean

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to understand how to properly implement a function to calculate the mathematical sample mean, with two initial required characteristics:

1) using variadic arguments.

2) not using two functions to do the job, that is, not using a caller function and then a second function that actually does the calculation.

3) function should be as generic as possible

I am very aware that a pretty similar question has been already asked: [Calculate the average of several values using a variadic-template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021067/calculate-the-average-of-several-values-using-a-variadic-template-function) However, while the accepted answer to that question seems to have taught the OP how to do the small part he didn't know, it presents a code that is actually wrong and does not compile.

So, my own first attempt was along these lines:

```
template <class... Args>
double mean(const Args & ... args)
{
    auto total = 0;
    for (auto value : { ...args })
    {
        total += value;
    }
    return (double)total / sizeof...(args);
}
```

The problem here is that in the line `auto total = 0;` the compile naturally can't automatically identify the type that object `total` should have.

Then, my second attempt:

```
template <class T, class... Args>
T mean(const T &t, const Args & ... args)
{
    T total = 0;
    for (auto value : { args... })
    {
        total += value;
    }
    return (T)(total / sizeof...(args));
}
```

That version the following problem. It does not work if the caller calls the function with arguments of mixed type, like in `mean(1, 2.5)`, where the first arguments is automatically detected as an `int` and the second is detected as a `double`.

I was able to solve that by doing the following:

```
template <class T, class... Args>
T mean(const T &t, const Args & ... args)
{
    size_t argsSize = sizeof...(args);
    T total = t;
    T arg_array[] = { args... };
    for (size_t i = 0; i< argsSize; i++)
    {
        total += (T)arg_array[i];
    }
    return (T)(total / argsSize) ;
}
```

This one works even when passed arguments are of different types (of course, provided that such types can be converted to `T`). The problem now, however, is that the function only works with a minimum of two arguments. If it is called like in `mean(3.14)`, while it should return 3.14, it actually raises an error because `T arg_array[] = { args... }` can't be compiled because it is impossible to have a static array be created with size `0`. Sure, I could substitute it for a dynamic array, but that would make me have to do one memory allocation and one memory deallocation every time that the function is called - which is an unacceptable waste.

So, what would be the correct way to implement such a function that avoids the mentioned problems and that follows my two initial conditions?

Comment: You need to get into the way of thinking recursively. The mean of one number is simply the value, which is your termination condition. The mean of N is the mean of the next N-1, times N-1, plus the top value, divided by N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem of "the function only works with a minimum of two arguments" you can create a simple type traits to extract the first type

```
template <typename T0, typename ...>
struct firstType
 { using type = T0; };
```

or, if you prefer (and, IMHO, is better), follow the `std::common_type_t` suggestion from Diego91b (+1).

You can write `mean()`, in C++11, as follows

```
template <typename ... Args>
typename firstType<Args...>::type mean (Args const & ... args)
// or typename std::common_type<Args...>::type mean (Args const & ... args)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   typename firstType<Args...>::type  total { 0 };
   // or typename std::common_type<Args...>::type  total { 0 };

   (void)unused { (total += args, 0)... };

   return total / sizeof...(args);
 }
```

In C++14 can be semplified (and transformed in `constexpr`) as follows

```
template <typename ... Args>
constexpr auto mean (Args const & ... args)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   //typename firstType<Args...>::type  total { 0 };
   std::common_type_t<Args...>  total { 0 };

   (void)unused { (total += args, 0)... };

   return total / sizeof...(args);
 }
```

In C++17 you can use fold expressions (as suggested by Passer By) and become realy easy

```
template <typename ... Args>
constexpr typename firstType<Args...>::type mean (Args const & ... args)
// or constexpr auto mean (Args const & ... args)
{
    return (... + args) / sizeof...(Args);
}
```

The following is a full compilable C++11 example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T0, typename ...>
struct firstType
 { using type = T0; };

template <typename ... Args>
typename firstType<Args...>::type mean (Args const & ... args)
// or typename std::common_type<Args...>::type mean (Args const & ... args)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   typename firstType<Args...>::type  total { 0 };
   // or typename std::common_type<Args...>::type  total { 0 };

   (void)unused { (total += args, 0)... };

   return total / sizeof...(args);
 }

int main()
 {
   std::cout << mean(2, 5.5) << std::endl; // print 3 (3.75 with common_type)
   std::cout << mean(5.5, 2) << std::endl; // print 3.75
   std::cout << mean(2) << std::endl;      // print 2
   // std::cout << mean() << std::endl; compilation error
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> do you know why exactly your solution gives 3 while using common_type gives 3.75 when calling mean(2, 5.5)?

Sure.

When you call `mean(2, 5.5)` using `firstType`, the type of the first argument is the type of `2`, that is `int`. So `total` is declared as `int` and when `5.5` is added to total, is converted to `int`, so become `5`, ad added to `2`. The `total` become `7` and divided by `2`, so (integer division) become `3`.

On the countrary, if you call `mean(5.5, 2)` the `firstType` is the type of `5.5` that is `double`. So `total` become a `double`, add `2` and `5.5` and obtain `7.5`. The last division (`7.5 / 2`) is a `double` division that give `3.75`.

When you call `mean(2, 5.5)` (or `mean(5.5, 2)`) using `std::common_type_t`, the common type between `int` and `double` is `double`; so `total` is defined as `double` and the function return `7.5 / 2` that is `3.75`.

**-- EDIT 2 --**

The OP ask

> Is there a particular reason why using unused has to be specifically assigned an `int[]`? I tried changing it to `typename std::common_type<Args...>::type`, which seems to me would make the function more generic, but then it does not compile. Also, it does not work with `double[]`.

The `unused` variable is ... unused.
Take in count that is declared only to permit, in it's initialization, to add in `total` the values of `args`, unpacking they.

The trick is the comma: observe

```
(total += args, 0)...
```

The comma discard the left value (that is computed, so `total` is modified, but discarted) and return the right value. That is zero. An integer zero. And for this reason is `int[]`.

The final result is that `unused` is initialized with `{ 0, 0, 0, ... }`.

There is no need to transform it in something of different type; it's only a trick to use the `args` pack.

If you want, you can do it (by example) `float`; as follows

```
using unused = float[];

(void)unused { (total += args, 0.0f)... };
```

(observe the `0.0f`) but... why we should do it?

Comment: Many thanks, that answer is fantastic. Quick and last follow up, for the sake of learning: do you know why exactly your solution gives `3` while using `common_type` gives `3.75` when calling `mean(2, 5.5)`?

Comment: @Juddy - answer improved; hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, I see. What is puzzling to me then is that the common type between `int` and `double` is `double`. But that is a matter for further study and eventually, if I can't understand, another different question. Thanks a lot for the answers

Comment: @Juddy - anser improved again; I'm not good in explaining my code but I hope you can understand the comma trick in `unused` because it's very useful (before C++17) in many variadic arguments uses.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::common_type_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):

```
template<class... Args> constexpr auto mean(Args... args) {
    std::common_type_t<Args...> total(0);
    for(auto value : {std::common_type_t<Args...>(args)...}) total += value;
    return total/sizeof...(args);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) in C++17

```
template<typename... Args>
constexpr decltype(auto) mean(Args&&... args)
{
    return (... + std::forward<Args>(args)) / sizeof...(Args);
}
```

The `std::forward` is there for some bignum types that supports moving.

Before C++17, manual folding is required, but that will require overloading `mean` for a base case, which seems like not what you want.

Comment: nice (+1), but you should precise that fold expressions are available starting from C++17.